# Generating a sequence of points in F# in a one-liner

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I find myself frequently implementing the same `(x, y)` pattern:

```
let rectangleSizes = seq {
    for w = 1 to width do
        for h = 1 to height do
            yield (w, h)
}
```

Wouldn't out there be a simple one-liner for this, by chance? Of course I could just write this very same function in just one line, but I feel its readability would suffer quite a bit:

```
let rectangleSizes = seq { for w = 1 to width do for h = 1 to height do yield (w, h) }
```

Comment: I had the second code snippet all edited because it made my eyes bleed then I realized it was critical to your question :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I had that initialization all the time I would define my own operator:

```
let (..) (x0,y0) (xn,yn) =  
    seq {
        for x = x0 to xn do
            for y = y0 to yn do
                yield (x, y)}

let rectangleSizes = {(1,1) .. (5,7)}
```

But this shadows the original `(..)` operator, however you can use another operator name or a function. Also there is a [trick](https://gist.github.com/gmpl/d66d1c2a3ac7972f3305) to avoid shadowing the original operator definition.

Alternatively if you use a library which implements Applicative Functors like [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) you can define it in one single line as:

```
let rectangleSizes = (fun x y -> (x, y)) <!> {1..width} <*> {1..height}
```

Note: The function `fun x y -> (x, y)` is usually called `tuple2`

```
#r @"FsControl.Core.dll"
#r @"FSharpPlus.dll"

open FSharpPlus
let tuple2 a b = (a,b)
let width, height = 5,7

let rectangleSizes = tuple2 <!> {1..width} <*> {1..height}
```

Comment: I think there's no trick available to avoid shadowing the library-defined range operator, therefore it's not a good idea at all. Theoretically you can provide a user-defined `op_Range` on a type, but if you try to use it, you'll get an _Unexpected symbol '..' in binding._ error. Possibly because of §3.6 of the spec, specifying that it is treated as a symbolic keyword.

Comment: @kaefer Anyway the tuple is a type which is already defined, still there is a trick to make it work, I just uploaded an example https://gist.github.com/gmpl/d66d1c2a3ac7972f3305 will link it to the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the fact that 2D arrays implement `IEnumerable`, which can be converted to `IEnumerable<'T>` (aka `seq<'T>`) using `Seq.cast`:

```
let rectangleSizes = Array2D.initBased 1 1 width height (fun w h -> (w, h)) |> Seq.cast<int * int>
```

Edit: This will create an array that stores all elements though, whereas your initial implementation generates them as needed. If your width and height are big, this may consume too much memory.

Answer (score 2):

You could save a teensy bit of space by :

```
let rectangleSizes = seq {
    for w = 1 to width do 
       for h = 1 to height -> (w, h)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to write

```
Seq.init width (fun w -> Seq.init height (fun h -> (w+1,h+1))) |> Seq.concat
```

or

```
seq [1 .. width] |> Seq.collect (fun w -> Seq.init height (fun h -> (w,h+1)))
```

Comment: A small simplification: `Seq.collect id` is `Seq.concat`.

Comment: How did I not realise that? Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `List.collect` and `List.map`:

```
let rectangleSizes = [1..width] |> List.collect (fun x -> [1..height] |> List.map (fun y -> (x,y)))
```

But in my opinion this is not as readable as your original solution using the `seq` constructor (and the evaluation is eager). I also prefer @Gustavo's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194175/848634) using an overloaded operator.

**Update:**

Lazy evaluation using sequences:

```
let rectangleSizes = {1..width} |> Seq.collect (fun x -> {1..height} |> Seq.map (fun y -> (x,y)))
```

Comment: The evaluation is eager because you use List.map and List.collect functions, use Seq.map and Seq.collect functions instead. You need to use also curly brackets instead of square.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know that the constructor `n..m` existed also for sequences.